# Возвращение анимации в исходную точку

Tags: css3, css-animation

У меня есть блок и он совершает движение вправо, затем вниз. После он должен поворачиваться на 145 градусов и застывать на месте, но место этого он поворачивается на 145 градусов и одновременно возвращается в исходное положение до всех анимаций. В чем моя ошибка ?

```
.box {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #f00;
position: absolute;
-webkit-animation: trans 1s linear forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes trans {
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 0px);
    }
    75%{
        -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 100px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(145deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
    .box {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #f00;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-animation: trans 1s linear;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    
    @-webkit-keyframes trans {
        50% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 0px);
        }
        75%{
            -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 100px);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 100px) rotate(145deg);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
  foo/bar
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Насколько я помню нужно написать  координаты последнего кадра.

Comment: > Насколько я помню нужно писать в координаты последнего кадра. Это вы про `transform-origin`? Если да, то он может быть где угодно в зависимости от задачи.

Comment: нет, я про       100% {-webkit-transform: translate(150px, 100px) rotate(145deg);}

Comment: А, это да. (.....)